# Xcode: Including third part frameworks for release?

Tags: xcode

I am currently trying to distribute a xcode project that is dependent on a third party framework to run. I edit the build so that it is for release, but when I try to run the app on another machine it says gives the following error:

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/third_party_framework/Versions/Current
   Referenced from: long file path 
   Reason: Image not found
```

Has anyone had experience with this problem or know how to fix it?
Edit: this is for a c++ program

Comment: Where are you expecting the 3rd party framework to be?  In /Library/Frameworks, in ~/Library/Frameworks, or inside your app bundle?

Comment: Inside of my app bundle I want to be able to ship it all as one file bundle the user downloads

Comment: Next obvious question: *Is* it in your bundle?  Does your project have a copy files build phase to put it there?

Comment: Yes, the framework is definitely there I think the main problem is that this framework is being stored at a very deep path inside of the users machine and I don't think that the code knows to look there for this framework. Would it be easier perhaps on installation to copy this framework into their /Library/Frameworks folder because then I am almost positive it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with putting a framework inside the app, assuming you are putting it in the Contents/Frameworks folder, the usual place.  The other part is setting up the install name right.  One way to do it is to go into the target build settings for the framework and set the "Installation Directory" build setting to `@executable_path/../Frameworks/`.  If memory serves, the other way to do it, using rpath, is to set the "Installation Directory" build setting in the framework target to `@rpath`, and also set the "Runpath Search Paths" build setting of the app target to `@executable_path/../Frameworks/`.

Comment: That seemed to do it I just need to change the search path and use the @executable_path variable.